# Change EditText Cursor Color in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have an `Entry` in my `ContentPage` and am doing rendering in Xamarin Android.
Here my problem is `EditText` background color is white and cursor color is also white.
Here I want to change the cursor color to black.
Is there any way to change the cursor color?
Here is my code.

**Entry to ExtendedEntry :**

```
public class ExtendedEntry : Entry { }
```

**Use ExtendedEntry in Content Page :**

```
var txtPhoneNumber = new ExtendedEntry { Placeholder = "Phone Number", Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric, TextColor = Color.Black };
```

**Render the ExtendedEntry in Xamarin Android :**

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedEntry), typeof(ExtendedEntryRender))]
namespace Project.Droid
{
    public class ExtendedEntryRender : EntryRenderer
    {
        // Override the OnElementChanged method so we can tweak this renderer post-initial setup
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {   // perform initial setup
                // lets get a reference to the native control
                var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText)Control;
                // do whatever you want to the textField here!
            nativeEditText.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.text_box);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the cursor color using:

```
IntPtr IntPtrtextViewClass = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(TextView));
IntPtr mCursorDrawableResProperty = JNIEnv.GetFieldID (IntPtrtextViewClass, "mCursorDrawableRes", "I");
JNIEnv.SetField (Control.Handle, mCursorDrawableResProperty, 0); // replace 0 with a Resource.Drawable.my_cursor
```

0 will keep the same color as the TextColor on your Entry.

Comment: you can combine the code pointed out here with platform effects, to avoid creating a derived class

Answer (score -2):

Edit: To change the cursur color the only option is to change the theme by adding for example:

Theme = "android:style/Theme.Holo.light" in MainActivity